# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"forms"'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using [idb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/idb) package for the project. In the add function I want to dynamically pass the `store name` to the function and the `store name` will be used directly in `this.db.put`

In the following line on variable `store`

```
return this.db.put(store, JSON.stringify(data), uuidv4());
```

I'm getting the following error.

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type
> '"forms"'

Here's the entire script of the service.

```
export class IndexedDbService {

  private db: IDBPDatabase<MyDB>;
  
  constructor(){
    this.connectToDb();
  }

  async connectToDb(){
    this.db = await openDB<MyDB>('MyDb', 1, {
      upgrade(db) {
        db.createObjectStore('forms');
      },
    });
  }

  add(store: string, data: object) {
    return this.db.put(store, JSON.stringify(data), uuidv4());
  }
}

interface MyDB extends DBSchema {
  'forms': {key: string; value: string; };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't the good solution but this the fast way to avoid.

```
add(store: string, data: object) {
  if (store === 'forms') {
    return this.db.put(store, JSON.stringify(data), uuidv4());
  }
}
```